# what does Key.of(2, 2) do in google spanner?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-spanner

I'm new to Google cloud Spanner and what does Key.of(2, 2) do in google cloud spanner?

import com.google.cloud.spanner.Key;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a key value to reference a primary key (or other index) with the values (2, 2). Assume that you have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FOO
(KEY1 INT64, KEY2 INT64, BAR STRING(100))
PRIMARY KEY (KEY1, KEY2)
```

Then Key.of(2,2) creates a key that will reference the row in the table where `KEY1=2 AND KEY2=2`.

You can use this key in read operations and mutation operations to specify which row you want to read or update/delete.

You can also use a key to read data using a secondary index instead of the primary key. Assume your table also has the following secondary index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IDX_FOO_BAR ON FOO (BAR)
```

Then you can read data from the table by filtering on the index value using a Key:

```java
DatabaseClient client = spanner.getDatabaseClient(...)
ResultSet resultSet =
  client
    .singleUse()
    .readUsingIndex(
      "FOO",
      "IDX_FOO_BAR",
      KeySet.range(KeyRange.closedOpen(Key.of("A"), Key.of("C"))),
                Arrays.asList("KEY1", "KEY2", "BAR");
```

The above will read all rows from the table FOO where `BAR>='A' AND BAR<'C'`.

Comment: how does this work with secondary indexes? e.g. a primary key of (key1, key2) and a secondary index of (key3)?

Comment: @foxygen I've added an example for using keys to read using a secondary index to the original answer